# 'heroku open' Opens Browser Tab with No Further Action

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I believe I've built out my application correctly in JavaScript and pushed it to Heroku properly. After running `heroku open` it does open a tab in Chrome albeit in a new window which is slightly annoying but that's it. It doesn't execute the Heroku URL. No URL is present.

However, when I paste in the URL into the browser's address bar it does execute properly. https://secret-basin-51587.herokuapp.com

Any idea why the Heroku URL isn't executing from my terminal?

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 397 bytes | 397.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.1.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.0.3
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.1.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.1.1...
remote:        npm 5.0.3 already installed with node
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        added 48 packages in 1.93s
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 16.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://secret-basin-51587.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/secret-basin-51587.git
   e088c9e..b31c862  master -> master
```

[image]

Comment: What does `$ heroku info`   print for your application?

Comment: `=== secret-basin-51587
Auto Cert Mgmt: false
Dynos:          web: 1
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/secret-basin-51587.git
Owner:          mikeyamato@gmail.com
Region:         us
Repo Size:      8 KB
Slug Size:      18 MB
Stack:          heroku-16
Web URL:        https://secret-basin-51587.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: that's pretty ugly. [try this link.](https://imgur.com/ZWeLh62)

Comment: All seems good, when you run the `$ heroku open` is there any output in the terminal?

Comment: there's a slight delay as it waits for the browser window to open up. then the terminal just goes to the next line. nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Hmm, this seems weird, I have not been able to reproduce this. Are you using latest chrome? Do you have some pop-up blockers which could affect the feature? Is your heroku cli up to date? (`$ heroku update`)

Comment: I feel like this is an episode of _The IT Crowd_ where they always ask if the person reporting the issue had turned off and on the machine. I was running version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit) of Chrome then it updated itself to version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) when you mentioned it. then just out of curiosity i ran it from my terminal and poof it magically started to work. wow. just wow. well this is embarrassing. thank you @Rikusor.

Comment: Today's IT world filled with packages and software, you can never remember to update everything all the time. Great you got it working! Now keep on building the future!